# PHP string-number comparing messing with zero's

Tags: php

Why is 0 equal to 0.0 in STRING comparisment?

```
<?php
    isset($_GET['temp'])?$temp=$_GET['temp']:$temp=0;
    if($temp == 0) {
        if ((string) $_GET['temp']==(string) '0.0'){
            $temp=0.01;
            print '='.$_GET['temp'].'=';
        }else{
            print '-'.$_GET['temp'].'-';
        }
    }else{
        print '+'.$_GET['temp'].'+';
    }
    print $temp;
?>
```

printed values are:

```
?temp=1    +1+1         (as expected)
?temp=0.0  =0.0=0.01    (as expected)
?temp=z    -z-z         (as expected)
?temp=0    =0=0.01      Wait...WHAT???
```

Where am I messing up? I'm sure its my fault, I just don't see where...
I tried it without the typejuggling also, same results...

EDIT:
try http://test.youp.net/stringcomparetest.php?temp=0 for testing, actual source code is shown there.

Comment: You say you "tried it without the typejuggling also" - but using a string cast (ie. `(string)`) doesn't avoid "type juggling" - in your example they are already strings, so the type cast is superfluous in this case.

Comment: @w3d: thas correct, but because it didn't give me the results I was expecting, I tried casting as well, resultless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is 0 equal to 0.0 in STRING comparisment?

Because numeric strings (ie. that satisfy `is_numeric()`) are first converted to a number and compared numerically. You need to use the identity operator (`===`) to compare types as well.

Reference: [PHP Comarison Operators](http://www.php.net/ternary)

Comment: Thanks! I used to do this when it was first introduced into PHP, but I forgot all about it.  I added this correction to the code in my examplepage (http://test.youp.net/stringcomparetest.php?temp=0) for future reference

Comment: You can also use PHP's [strcmp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function if you want to enforce a string comparison - this might be easier to read than `===`.